# What is the alternative to Custom Pagination Presenter in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, Custom Presenters have been removed? Does anyone know what the alternative is in Laravel 5 to adjust the class names and view data?

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#custom-presenters

Comment: Here is the post for Laravel 5.8 about how to extend core pagination: stackoverflow.com/a/58005778/1916821

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5 custom pagination is based on presenters (classes) instead of views.

Assuming in your routed code you have

```
$users = Users::paginate(15);
```

In L4 you used to do something like this in your views:

```
$users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->links();
```

In L5 you do instead:

```
$users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->render();
```

The `render()` method accepts an `Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Presenter` instance. You can create a custom class that implements that contract and pass it to the `render()` method.

Alternatively you can extend the Laravel paginator (in order to use its pagination logic) and then pass the existing pagination instance (`$users->...`) to you extended class constructor. This is indeed what I did for creating my custom [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) presenter based on the Bootstrap presenter provided by Laravel. It uses all the Laravel pagination logic and only overrides the rendering methods.

With my custom presenter my views look like this:

```
with(new \Stolz\Laravel\Pagination($users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])))->render();
```

And my customized pagination presenter is:

```
<?php namespace Stolz\Laravel;

use Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapThreePresenter;

class Pagination extends BootstrapThreePresenter
{
    /**
     * Convert the URL window into Zurb Foundation HTML.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        if( ! $this->hasPages())
            return '';

        return sprintf(
            '<ul class="pagination" aria-label="Pagination">%s %s %s</ul></div>',
            $this->getPreviousButton(),
            $this->getLinks(),
            $this->getNextButton()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get HTML wrapper for disabled text.
     *
     * @param  string  $text
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDisabledTextWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="unavailable" aria-disabled="true"><a href="javascript:void(0)">'.$text.'</a></li>';
    }

    /**
     * Get HTML wrapper for active text.
     *
     * @param  string  $text
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getActivePageWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="current"><a href="javascript:void(0)">'.$text.'</a></li>';
    }

    /**
     * Get a pagination "dot" element.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDots()
    {
        return $this->getDisabledTextWrapper('&hellip;');
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but I'm trying to do exactly what @javi-stolz did and it is not calling my overridden `getActivePageWrapper` method. It still calls the one from `BootstrapThreePresenter`. Anyone else having this issue?